# Can't show image from kml file using google maps api v3 and geoxml3

Tags: maps, kml

i try to put my kml file on google maps using geoxml3. here is the code`

```js
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/branches/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
```

```js
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-3.899540, 104.463014);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    myParser = new geoXML3.parser({map: map});
    myParser.parse('bpnsumsel.kml');

  }
</script>
`
```

but nothing shows up.
any idea?

update:

my kml file looks like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0"><GroundOverlay><name> MapInfo Saved View</name><visibility>1</visibility><Icon><href>Peta BPN Sumsel.JPG</href></Icon><LatLonBox><north>-3.378408</north><south>-4.506592</south><east>105.590007</east><west>103.723993</west><rotation>0</rotation></LatLonBox></GroundOverlay></kml>
```

yes. i don't include ProjectedOverlayed.js
is there any good tutorial for full code example?

thanks

Comment: What does "nothing shows up" mean? Does the map show? Do you get any javascript errors? what does you KML look like?

Comment: no problem about the map. but my image in kml file is not plot to the map. my kml file looks like this.    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0"><GroundOverlay><name> MapInfo Saved View</name><visibility>1</visibility><Icon><href>Peta BPN Sumsel.JPG</href></Icon><LatLonBox><north>-3.378408</north><south>-4.506592</south><east>105.590007</east><west>103.723993</west><rotation>0</rotation></LatLonBox></GroundOverlay></kml>'

Comment: Please edit your question to add the KML to it, it is hard to read in the comments.  It doesn't look like you are including ProjectedOverlay.js which is required for GroundOverlays. [Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_KML_samples_test.html)

Comment: i am sorry. i already edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/wiki/Usage):

> The geoxml3 library is specifically designed to accomodate a range of use cases, covering
>   developer needs from beginner to advanced. In all cases, you'll need to download a copy of 
>   geoxml3.js (and ProjectedOverlay.js, if you want ground overlays) from this site and serve 
>   them to your map page from your own host, as follows:

```js
  <script type="text/javascript" src="geoxml3.js"></script>
[ <script type="text/javascript" src="ProjectedOverlay.js"></script> ]
```

Comment: i update my code. i include ProjectOverlay.js but the code only shows the map without an image in kml file.

Comment: Do you have a live example, or can you make a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem?  [My example works](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_KML_samples_test.html), click on Mt Edna.

Comment: yes i try to show an image. it is like mt etna in your example work. i dont have a live example. i build a web application just for my office local network.

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors or interesting messages in the console?

Comment: there is no error message in my browser. would you mind give me a simple code just for show or plot image in kml file to google map. thanks.